# expecting do error while writing multiple files in a bash loop

Tags: bash

I am using the command below to get multiple files 2_intents.txt, 3_intents.txt ... etc using the rows I have in a file

```
sh -c "for i in $(seq 2 55); do  head -${i} 55_intents_total.txt > ${i}_intents.txt ; done"
```

but I am getting this error

```
sh: 2: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting "do")
```

Update: I found the problem that it does run when I put in explicitly in bash script but not from command line with sh -c

Comment: The problem is the kind of quotes you're using with `sh -c`. Needs to be single, not double. As it is, the `$(seq)` and all the `${i}`s are expanded **before** the `sh` command is first invoked.

Comment: If you run `set -x; sh -c "..."` (with your original command in place of the `...`), the log emitted will show the immediate effect of that error, and thus make the failure mechanism obvious.

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr: You need to either single quote the whole expression or use a space separator for the arguments (`seq -s ' '`).

A simpler version of your code shows the issue:

```
$ bash --noprofile --norc -o xtrace
bash-4.4$ sh -c "for i in $(seq 1 2); do echo $i; done"
++ seq 1 2
+ sh -c 'for i in 1
2; do  echo ; done'
sh: -c: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `2'
sh: -c: line 1: `2; do  echo ; done'
```

So this is equivalent to running a shell script containing this:

```
for i in 1
2; do  echo ; done
```

If I run the inner expression in the shell it does what I expect:

```
bash-4.4$ for i in $(seq 1 2); do echo $i; done
++ seq 1 2
+ for i in $(seq 1 2)
+ echo 1
1
+ for i in $(seq 1 2)
+ echo 2
2
```

The reason for this must be the sequence of the expansions: in your original code the sequence is expanded before setting up the `for` loop, but in the last example above the loop is set up *before* the sequence is expanded. I can't find a reference for this though.

Comment: I did try to insert the semi-colon but getting the same error.

Comment: Ok it does work inside a bash script but not from command line.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the command substitution and variable reference are being expanded *before* the string (command) is passed to `sh`. Thus, what gets executed is the equivalent of:

```
sh -c "for i in 2
3
4
5
...
54
55; do  head - 55_intents_total.txt > _intents.txt ; done"
```

...and `sh` gets confused by having a line break before it gets to the `do`. Even if that weren't a problem, the two references to `${i}` both got replaced by, well, nothing, because `$i` isn't defined yet.

The simplest solution is to wrap the command in single-quotes instead of double-quotes:

```
sh -c 'for i in $(seq 2 55); do  head -${i} 55_intents_total.txt > ${i}_intents.txt ; done'
```

Alternately, you could escape the `$`s to keep the current shell from interpreting them:

```
sh -c "for i in \$(seq 2 55); do  head -\${i} 55_intents_total.txt > \${i}_intents.txt ; done"
```